# DIFFERENT VIEWS OF ACTIVITIES

Tags: android

I tried to run my android application of simple log in form using my smartphone but it brings different view from one I created in my computer and that one appears on my smartphone. How can I resolve it?

On my android studio appearance

[image]

On my smartphone

[image]

Comment: Please send Your XML Code

Comment: Add the xml code to the question